# Text Animation in android

Tags: android, animation, textview

I want to animate the text of the textview not the whole textview in Android application. I am currently using `Marquee` property of Android textview but it is not 100% what i want, so i want to animate the text inside the textView so i can handle the events also. If someone with work around on this, please share your answers.
thanks

Here is what i have done at the moment using Marquee

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what kind of animation you want

Comment: Hi, please check my edited answer. I want horizontal text animation in right to left direction. Marquee problems: does not scroll if text is not exceeding the textview (I want to animate text both ways). 2. Dont have any completion detection event so i can run a piece of code (I want to change text on completion).